# Addition of vector but with same direction

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I was playing around with vectors and i got stuck at thing that i think should work.Please correct me if i m wrong as it was today that i realised that vectors are nothing but just graphical representation of co ordinates in a way .

I took two position vectors in first quadrant.

r1=2i+4j

r2=5i+5j

So adding r1 and r2 should give me a third vector let us say r3 which should have length 7i+9j which turns out to be $\sqrt130$ and this should be equal to length of r1+r2 which is $\sqrt20$ + $\sqrt50$ but it turns out that $\sqrt130$ is not exactly equal to $\sqrt20$ + $\sqrt50$
Why is it so it should be exactly same right ?

> Blockquote

Comment: It is not true that $\|v_1+v_2\|=\|v_1\|+\|v_2\|$.  Instead, you have $\|v_1+v_2\|\leq \|v_1\|+\|v_2\|$ and equality occurs if *and only if* $v_1$ and $v_2$ are scalar multiples of one another.  See [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) on wikipedia.

Comment: "*Vectors are nothing but just graphical representation of coordinates in a way*"  The vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ perhaps which are the types of vectors you will mostly be working with at an early level, but vectors can live in far more abstract settings than that.

Comment: I understood where i was wrong but can you just explain what did u mean by "v1 and v2 are scalar multiples of one another"

Comment: nonzero vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are scalar multiples of one another if and only if there exists a scalar $\alpha$ such that $v_1=\alpha v_2$.  For example $(1,0,2,3)$ is a scalar multiple of $(4,0,8,12)$ since $(1,0,2,3)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot (4,0,8,12)$

Answer (score 1):

That's because the angle between those two vectors is small but not $0$. If it was $0$ (that is, if $r_2=\lambda r_1$ for some $\lambda>0$), then the length of the sum would indeed be the sum of the lengths. But in your case the sum is the diagonal of a parallelogram (see the picture below) and the length of such a diagonal is always strictly smaller than the sum of the lengths of two non-parallel sides.

[image]

Comment: Thank you i understood where i was wrong

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.